# sending mail from dynamic alias id

Tags: google-apps-script

Looking solution for sending mail from dynamic alias id.

Send mail from alias id's,  I have multiple alias ids (add as send mail under account )

```
      {from:"alias@domain.com"});____________ Is working fine
```

however i have dynamic sender list in my sheet hence  wants to pull the from id from sheet

using "  {from:row[3]}); however it's not working . 
Please help me to fix this.

```js
function emailNotification() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
  var toNotify = 'xyz@abc.com';
  var submitter = sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Email Address")).getValue();
  var subject = sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("Subject")).getValue();
  var description = sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("Description")).getValue();


  GmailApp.sendEmail(toNotify,+ lastRow + " " + subject,
                    "\n\nDESCRIPTION OF ISSUE:\n" + description +
                    "\n\nSubmitter: " + submitter + ",          
                   {from:row[3]});
}


function getColIndexByName(colName) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var row = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numColumns).getValues();
  for (i in row[0]) {
    var name = row[0][i];
    if (name == colName) {
      return parseInt(i) + 1;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 4 of your code sets row to be the index of the active `Range`

```
var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
```

This is an integer not an object. Are you looking to specify a specific cell? Or do you want instead to get the entire range or specify a range between the top of the active sheet and the last row?

Also, your `sendMail()` includes the `lastRow` in the subject line, is this what you want?

Comment: This I understand except that in that context `row` is an integer because that is what `.getRowIndex()` returns and not an object so `row[3]` makes no sense

Comment: Please refer line 12                          (  {from:row[3]});)            

In sheet row number 3 i have the list of email address and i want to send from this ids.I don't  want to mention the email address in the script (It works when i mention the email address in line 12) It should pick the from address from row number 3+

Comment: i have replaced with sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Email Address")).getValue();
not working for me

Comment: so its the same as submitter?

Comment: Yes, I have added submitters id as an alias (Send Mail) what's to generate email from submitters id

Comment: Thanks It worked with 
var alias = sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("Business User")).getValue()